# Extracting span tags using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract span tags using beautifulsoup, the code is giving no output

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
tags  = soup("span")
for tag in tags:
  print(tag)
```

tag:`<tr><td>Romina</td><td><span class="comments">97</span></td></tr>`

please help me!!
Thank you

Comment: It's `soup.find("span")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call find() or find_all() functions with the target tag as the argument, optionally with other constraints (e.g. class name or id) to filter the HTML elements. For more info see [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find).

Try this:

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<table>
<tr><td>Romina</td><td><span class="comments">97</span></td></tr>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for elt in soup.find_all("span", class_="comments"):
    print(elt.text)
```

**Output:**

```
97
```

If want to store the elements in a list can use list comprehension.

```
data = [elt.text for elt in soup.find_all("span", class_="comments")]
```

Comment: I need to store this output (which is 97 in this case) to a variable. How Could I do that?

Comment: @ArunodaGunawardanaAdee update answer to store extacted results in a list

Comment: for elm in glomark['offers']:
      print(elm['price'])

Can you please tell me how do I store the returning value of the above for loop to a variable?

Comment: @ArunodaGunawardanaAdee answer now shows how to store the list in a variable called data. See last line in updated answer.